# Angular issue with $scope and $routeParams

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to run a function if someone hits the submit button OR there is a value in routeParams (if user hits the page with param already filled out.) I would like a function to run. Im having a brain fart and can't seem to get this to work!

```
myApp.config([ '$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/:params?', {
         templateUrl: 'myTemplate',
         controller : 'myController'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/'
    });
} ]);

myApp.controller('ipCntrl', function($scope,$log,$http,$q,$routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.runReport = function() {
        $location.search({'ip': $routeParams['ip']})
    }


});

myApp.controller('myController', function($scope,$log,$http,$q,$routeParams, $location) {

if ($routeParams['ip'])
{
    $scope.ip = $routeParams['ip'];
    runMyFunction();
}



<div  ng-controller="ipCntrl">

            <form ng-submit="runReport()">
                <input class="form-control" ng-model="ip">

            </form>
    <div ng-view ></div>
</div>

<script type="text/ng-template" id="myTemplate">
HI!
</script>
```

Comment: What is the issue right now? Im guessing its running every time even if there is no route param?

Comment: I don't see any `ip` parameter in the route

Comment: Use $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ ... }) in your controller's function to intercept state transition. https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events

Answer (score 0):

Since you're trying to call a function on button click or on initialization after checking the `$routeParams`, just include that code in the angular controller you are using (`ipCntrl`)

```
myApp.controller('ipCntrl', function($scope,$log,$http,$q,$routeParams, $location) {

    $scope.runReport = function() {
        $location.search({'ip': $routeParams['ip']})
    }

    //Just put the if statement here
    //you're already using the ng-submit to call this function from your form
    if ($routeParam.ip != null) //other definition check logic
        $scope.runReport();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use...

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', 
function(event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams){ 

     console.log('toState ->');
     console.log(toState);

     console.log('toParams ->');
     console.log(toParams);

     console.log('fromState ->');
     console.log(fromState);

     console.log('fromParams ->');
     console.log(fromParams);

     runMyFunction();
})
```

...in your controller's function to intercept state transitions and requested URls ($stateParams). 
See [State Change Events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#state-change-events).

You also have [View Load events](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki#view-load-events) that may be useful.

You can also intercept state changes (and evaluate requested routes) in Angular's .run().
See .run() ui-router's [Sample App](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/sample/).